# Can eslint use same rule on tslint?

Tags: eslint, tslint

I am using eslint for nodejs backend but curious if I can use the same rule from tslint?

I would like to know if rules from tslint will work in eslint rule.

Answer (score 0):

NodeJS and Typescript have little to do with each other, so likely these rules are too specific.

Therefore, trying to lint apples with a pear-linter won't yield the desired results.

Comment: Are you sure about that? TypeScript want to move to ESLint:
https://eslint.org/blog/2019/01/future-typescript-eslint

Comment: @Minijack this might work for the generated JS ... and "wants to" is not "does". Besides, the availability of classes in JS since ECMAScript 2015 makes TS merely obsolete. In every case, these would be a different set of validation rules.